# C++. Построение графиков функций

Tags: c++, c++builder

Среда - borland c++ builder 6. В общем моя цель такая что пользователь вводит функцию, а программа строит ее график. Как построить график и найти значения функции я примерно знаю. Проблема вот в чем: как нам получить функцию из edita чтобы с ней работать. Ведь мы получаем строку, а как в нее значения подставлять и вообще с ней работать?

Comment: [Обратная польская запись](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C)

Comment: [Обратная польская запись: примеры реализации](https://ru.wikiversity.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C:_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8)

Comment: Существуют целые математические пакеты, типа Mapple. Насколько близко вы хотите к ним приблизиться? Возможно, стоит реализовать несколько вариантов, а потом думать о парсере произвольных функций, т.к. вы точно встретитесь со всевозможными "приколами", например, точками разрыва.

Comment: @LXA что за пакеты? А в чем проблема точек разрыва, цикл будет просто перебирать значения в заданном промежутке и строить по ним график

Comment: Уже упомянутый Maple, а также Wolfram Mathematica, Maxima. Особенные точки нужно будет искать автоматически и обрабатывать специфически. Далеко не все функции будут подчиняться вашему предположению о плавности, непрерывности, поэтому нельзя использовать равные промежутки по оси абсцисс.

Comment: @LXA не могли бы вы привести пример такой необычной сложной функции

Comment: y = 1/x; методом ad-hoc можно повышать сложность. Даже квадратный корень потребует анализа области определения. А вы говорите, пройти по координатам в цикле.

Comment: @LXA ну и в чем проблема то построить эту гиперболу.. подставить значения и все...

Comment: Хорошо, какое значение y при x = 0? С каким шагом нужно к нему подходить? Собираетесь ли вы вообще анализировать область определения?

Comment: @LXA в таком случае анализ простой: встретили деление-исключаем 0 других правил вроде бы нет

Comment: Ага, скажите это функции y = sqrt(x) или y = ln(x). Эти простые функции уже не удовлетворяют вашему предположению. В целом, моё мнение, нужно проводить полноценный анализ функции. Это значит, точки пересечения с нулем и точки перегиба, а это первая и вторая производные. Вы готовы найти их в аналитическом виде? Для произвольной (!) функции?

Answer (score 1):

1. Парсите строку
2. Строите дерево выражений
3. Выполняете дерево, подставив нужные переменные
4. Рисуете результат

[Пример](https://rsdn.ru/article/files/Classes/tparser.xml) (простой, но содержит ошибки)

Comment: Но ведь функций неисчислимое множество, это и дерево выражений бесконечное будет чтоли?

Comment: @NikHaker, вы же парсите только одну строку - и получите только одно дерево

Comment: @Grundy В одной строке может содержаться огромное количество вариантов. Или я не правильно понял, обьясните чуть подробнее про дерево

Comment: @NikHaker, для математических выражений вам не нужно строить дерево, смотрите ссылки которые я дал в комментариях к посту

Answer (score 0):

Как я понимаю, необходим синтаксический анализатор. Обратите внимание на `QScript` и `QScriptEngine` из билиотек Qt

Comment: это вроде уже новый язык ?

Comment: это скриптовый язык. Скрипт встраивается в код и интерпретируется при помощи QScriptEngine. Не могу похвастать опытом работы с этим. Но вот неплохая статья [ссылка](http://blog.harrix.org/?p=1787). Тут видно, что особого изучения синтаксиса практически не требуется. Либо делайте, как описано zenden2k и Grundy, но тогда всё ручками